# how to get image icon to align right in a Linear Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I know there are lots of threads with more or less same topic but none of them covers my situation:

I have a little garbage can for the delete button but it always disappears off the screen if the line of the text is too long and if its too short it's attached to the line  and I just wanted to be on the right hand side of the app like the the Add_item button but since it is in a Linear Layout it does not work

**ativity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.owner.test24.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/header"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/accent"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/header"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/header"
    android:src="@drawable/add_item_button"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_item"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/todo_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**to_do_item_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDel"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_button"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    />
```

if someone has solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use it, it works on every screen size

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.03"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hhhhh"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.87"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDel"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do I have to add weight for all views, as Checkbox and ImageButton width are almost fixed in size?

Comment: I knew it. But is it necessary for a fixed width view? I may add this if all of the views width are dynamic in size.

Comment: @  Md Sufi Khan     yes, it will works for dynamic width,its not necessary to add all the Views, as you had post ur answer it will be alse acceptable

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood me. There is room that I can learn more from you or anyone. I am just discussing to know more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try below one

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Hopes it will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Welcome. If you accept the answer then it will help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `layout_gravity` tag

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Weight:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weighSum= "1">

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkBox"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
amdroid: layout_weight="0.2"
/>
```

```
 <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnDel"
android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_button"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Delete"
amdroid: layout_weight="0.2"
/>
```